# Floor drain is overflowing next to furnace

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, drain, condensation, overflow

We have our furnace on the second floor of our home. There is a pvc pipe coming from the top part and it leads to what looks like a floor drain. The last couple of weeks when our air conditioner is on, I have noticed water dripping into the drain from the pipe and it has overflown once. I shut it off, got as much water as I could put with paper towels so it wasn’t over flowing from the drain. Most days when the air conditioner is on, the pvc pipe drips but isn’t in danger of overflowing. On random days (or seemingly random to me), the drain gets close to over flowing and I have to turn off my air conditioner and get more water out.

A couple of other notes. When I roll up a few sheets of paper towel and put it in the drain, water will get sucked up and the level goes down but the second I pull it out, the water starts to go up and down until it settles, almost like there is a tank beside it and the water is leveling off in both places. Today it is extremely hot and humid, and the pipe is dripping more and starts overflowing after an hour or so.

I believe the dripping is normal into the pipe and I believe the pipe is clogged some where but I am not too familiar with it so I could be wrong. Is this something I could potentially fix if I had a drain snake? I also just had my ac unit replaced (not actual furnace too) last summer. Should I call the guy who replaced it to come take a look?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can try hot water and Chlorox but in my experience once my drain was clogged there was insufficient flow for that to work. I had to snake mine. Yours looks like it would be pretty easy to do.

Comment: I wonder if that PVC insert is covering a full sized floor drain and can be removed for snaking it out?